# Exception thrown: 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll when using a SELECT query

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, winforms, xamarin.forms

```
try
{
    string connString = "server=db4free.net;port=3306;database=secretdb;user id=secret;password=secret;charset=utf8";
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connString);
    conn.Open();
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT School_Name FROM schools WHERE School_ID=@id", conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", "1");
    var schoolName = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    label1.Text = schoolName.ToString();
    conn.close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

The code above returns the exception **Exception thrown: 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException' in mscorlib.dll**

However whenever I used a query such as **INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE it works just fine**. Just like the code below:

```
try
{
    string connString = "server=db4free.net;port=3306;database=secretdb;user id=secret;password=secret;charset=utf8";
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connString);
    conn.Open();
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO schools(School_Name,School_Address) VALUES(@name,@address)", conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", "Sample Name");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", "Sample Address");
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    label1.Text = "Success";
    conn.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

So basically my problem is the following:

1. The first block of code works just fine if used in **Xamarin.Forms** (tested in Android). I can SELECT from the database.
2. The first block of code doesn't work if used in **Windows Forms App** and returns the said exception. Both Xamarin.Forms and Windows Forms App runs on C# so I don't exactly know why this is happening.
3. The second block of code works just fine in both **Xamarin.Forms** and **Windows Forms App**.
4. Basically, I can run any SQL query but not SELECT.

Comment: Does a `cmd.Prepare();` command help right after declaring the query? Also I see some references to leaving out the `@` sign on the `AddWithValue` call.

Comment: have you checked if the actual query returns any value?

Comment: Also can you point us where exactly the code says there's an error? because the exception being thrown "System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException" is related collections

Comment: Where does the exception occur? I which line exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your code could leave a connection open in case an exception occurs. The `conn.Close()` should be moved to a `finally` block.
Second, to query the values you should use the `cmd.ExecuteReader()` method, which will return a `MySqlDataReader` object; to Dispose it, you can use the `using()` construct. The `ExecuteScalar()` method is meant for insert/update/delete statements and returns the number of rows affected.

Third, but not less important: consider moving your database-related code to a Repository class, then call you repository class code from the Form logic. This way you will have a reusable piece of code.
A simple example of the starting point for a repository class:

```
public class Repository
{
    public string ConnectionString { get; private set; }

    public Repository(string connectionString)
    {
        this.ConnectionString = connectionString;
    }

    public string GetSchoolNameById(int id)
    {
        string schoolName = null;
        MySqlConnection conn = null;
        try
        {
            conn = new MySqlConnection(this.ConnectionString);
            conn.Open();
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT School_Name FROM schools WHERE School_ID=@id";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
                using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (rdr.Read())
                    {
                        if (!rdr.IsDBNull(rdr.GetOrdinal("School_Name")))
                        {
                            schoolName = rdr.GetString(rdr.GetOrdinal("School_Name"));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // maybe log exception here, or rethrow it if you want
            // the consumer to manage it. This depends on how you plan to build your software architecture.
        }
        finally
        {
            // this code will run always, either if everything ran correctly or if some exception occurred in the try block.
            if (conn != null)
            {
                conn.Close();
                conn.Dispose();
            }
        }
        return schoolName;
    }

}
```

Then, your form code could be as simple as:

```
    Repository rep = new Repository("server=db4free.net;port=3306;database=secretdb;user id=secret;password=secret;charset=utf8");
    try
    {
        // the try/catch is necessary if you have decided to re-throw the exception in the Repository.GetSchoolNameById method
        label1.Text = rep.GetSchoolNameById(1);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
```

Comment: isn't `MySqlConnection` also disposable ? So also needs to be in a `Using()`construct ?

Comment: I have omitted the MySqlConnection disposal because 1) I forgot to, and 2) I wanted to focus on the specific problem. Disposing the connection is an excellent idea and it should be done. But I think that the most important thing to do here is to Close the Connection. Usually the Garbage Collector will gracefully manage the task of disposing the connection, if the rest of the code is written correctly.

Comment: Anyway, the using() {} construct is just a short form to have the object disposed here. It is not the only way. You could just add `conn.Dispose();` in the finally block right after the conn.Close();.

Comment: Disposable objects should always get the `Dispose();`called. In your code it is not, so you should either add it or use a `Using()`construct. And yes it does not matter for the problem of the OP but since you brought the `Using()` up in your answer I think you should be consistent.

Comment: @GuidoG you are right, I've edited my answer and added the Dispose() call.

Comment: Much better I give you now +1